# JQuery UI : Sortable - Which event should I use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I've a problem while working with JQuery UI. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

- I have a sortable list ( `.form_container` ), with objects. When their position are changed, ajax call updates the DB.
- Outside of this list, I've got "text items" ( `.create_item` ). When those items are being dropped on the sortable list, I want to make an ajax call that will give me the content so I can transform my simple item into an object.
- THEN, because a new object has been added, I want the ajax calls for position being fired. But not before my new object is properly loaded.

I hope I'm clear enough...

So first, I though about doing something like that

**First Attempt :**

```
$(".create_item").draggable({
  containment: 'window',
  connectToSortable: ".form_container",
  helper: "clone",
});
$(".form_container").droppable({
  accept: ".create_item",
  tolerance: 'fit',
  over: function(event,ui) {
    // Something here
  },
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    // Ajax calls that changes my item into an object
  }
});
$(".form_container").sortable({
  axis: "y",
  containment: ".form_container",
  revert: true,
  update: function(event, ui){
    // Ajax calls that update positions in DB
  }         
});
```

Problem is, `connectToSortable` also triggers the **drop** event so this event is called twice thus causing trouble.

So I've followed someone's advice on SOF, and changed my code for something like that.

**Second Attempt :**

```
$(".create_item").draggable({
  containment: 'window',
  connectToSortable: ".form_container",
  helper: "clone",
});
$(".form_container").droppable({
  accept: ".create_item",
  tolerance: 'fit',
  over: function(event,ui) {
    // Something here
  }
  // No more drop function
});
$(".form_container").sortable({
  axis: "y",
  containment: ".form_container",
  revert: true,
  update: function(event, ui){
    // Ajax calls that update positions in DB
  },
  receive: function(event,ui) {
    // Ajax calls that changes my item into an object
  }         
});
```

Problem is, the **update** event is triggered before the **receive** event is finished and my item hasn't been transformed properly into a nice object.

That's about everything, can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first attempt, as far as I know, double drop call is known issue (http://url.ba/o88p). I can only suggest some workaround by declaring some global variable (counter), and then use it to make call every second time:

```
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    if (counter++%2) {
        // Ajax calls that changes my item into an object
    }
  }
```

Regarding your second attempt I think solution is a little bit elegant. First, declare your update method using bind (only if you bind it this way you can trigger it manually).

```
var _updateFunction = function(event, ui){
    // logic for update, ajax calls, etc.
};
$('.form_container').bind('sortupdate', _updateFunction);
```

Now, create received function that will look something like this:

```
receive: function(event,ui) {
    // don't let update be called
    $('.form_container').unbind('sortupdate');

    $
      // call to create object using ajax
      .ajax()
      // when this call is finished
      .done(function() {
          $('.form_container')
              .bind('sortupdate', _updateFunction)
              .trigger('sortupdate');
      })
}
```

Here is this example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7jPAv/

Comment: Great answer. Seems to work (and I'm talking about your second solution, the first one seems a little bit too hacky). I've now trouble to get the clone item in the sortable but it's another problem. Thanks a lot anyways !